# Matching elements in Linked List

Tags: java, linked-list

Basically I am searching a linked list for matching elements between users. It is basically a dating type service. The user clicks the search button and the code is run and it compiles matches and prints them out to a text field.

**Link to Account Class:** http://pastebin.com/jnBrcnP1

**Here is what the Linked List looks like:**

```
tobi
tobi123
tobi@hotmail.com
tobi
Mixed Breed
Male
1-2
Virginia
Walking
peppy
peppy123
peppy@hotmail.com
peppy
Chihuahua
Male
5-6
Virginia
Eating
```

**Here is my button code:**

```
private void jButtonS1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
    LinkedList<Account> account = new LinkedList<Account>();
    String username = jTextFieldS1.getText();

    if(username.equals("")) // If password and username is empty > Do this >>>
    {
        jButtonS1.setEnabled(false);
        jTextFieldS1.setText("");
        jButtonS1.setEnabled(true);
        this.setVisible(true);
    }
    else
    {

        for(Account acc : account)
        {
            if(acc.getUsername().equals(username)){
                acc.goToNext();
                acc.goToNext();
                acc.goToNext();
                acc.goToNext();
                String breed = acc.getDataAtCurrent();
                acc.goToNext();
                String gender = acc.getDataAtCurrent();
                acc.goToNext();
                acc.goToNext();
                String state = acc.getDataAtCurrent();

                if(acc.getUsername().equals(username)== false && acc.getBreed().equals(breed) && acc.getGender().equals(gender)== false && acc.getState().equals(state)){
                    String match = acc.getUsername();
                    jTextAreaS1.setText("User: " + match + "is a 90% match!");
                }

                if(acc.getUsername().equals(username)== false && acc.getBreed().equals(breed) && acc.getGender().equals(gender)== false){
                    String match = acc.getUsername();
                    jTextAreaS1.setText("User: " + match + "is a 70% match!");
                }

                if(acc.getUsername().equals(username)== false && acc.getBreed().equals(breed) && acc.getState().equals(state)){
                    String match = acc.getUsername();
                    jTextAreaS1.setText("User: " + match + "is a 70% match!");
                }

                if(acc.getUsername().equals(username)== false && acc.getState().equals(state) && acc.getGender().equals(gender)== false){
                    String match = acc.getUsername();
                    jTextAreaS1.setText("User: " + match + "is a 70% match!");
                }

                if(acc.getUsername().equals(username)== false && acc.getBreed().equals(breed)){
                    String match = acc.getUsername();
                    jTextAreaS1.setText("User: " + match + "is a 50% match!");
                }

                if(acc.getUsername().equals(username)== false && acc.getGender().equals(gender)== false){
                    String match = acc.getUsername();
                    jTextAreaS1.setText("User: " + match + "is a 50% match!");
                }

                if(acc.getUsername().equals(username)== false && acc.getState().equals(state)){
                    String match = acc.getUsername();
                    jTextAreaS1.setText("User: " + match + "is a 50% match!");
                }

            }

        }

        try
        {
            read(account, "doggydates.txt");
        } catch (Exception e)
        {
            System.err.println(e.toString());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Is this a question ? What is that you need to accomplish here ? Please mention it.

Comment: What is your question exactly?

Comment: You haven't asked a question. I'd also *strongly* advise you to redesign your `Account` API - an account *isn't* really a simple collection to be iterated; why would you want to treat the data that way? What possible benefit is there in treating (say) gender and age as just "elements in a collection"? You're explicitly *finding* the breed anyway, after a seemingly-arbitrary-but-presumably-magic-number of calls to `goToNext()`. Why aren't you just calling `getBreed()` directly?

Comment: Well my question I guess is that this code is messed up and I dont know what im doing wrong. I know im using goToNext but thats because when I find the user node I have to go to the next node to get other values.

Comment: Haha... funny you have to guess yourself what the question is ;-)

Answer (score 1):

1) First thing you need to do is to create a class(say Account) with different attributes like 'First Name','LastName','userID','breed', etc..

2) Whenever you collect the details from the user, create an object of Account class and store all the attributes(May be you can use parameterized constructor with all attributes).

Eg:`Account acc=new Account(FirstName,Age,Sex,Breed...);`

3) Store these in a collection and use it later so that you can simply do a `getBreed()` or `getAge()`

4)Last but not the least, take a break, clear your head, design what you are planning to implement and then, hit the system.

Answer (score 0):

Couple of things here, first this isn't a question, you are stating your program and that's it, but scanning through your code you've more than one problem.

Your first problem is the design, obviously you've an entity called account which can have the name, username, email address, breed, gender and whatever you want. You'll have to create a class for it (if you want to follow OOP) or simply a struct if you prefer to skip OOP. You are using Java so I believe that you should go with the OOP solution. It will make your life easier.

```
public class account {
    private String name, user_name, email, .... ;
    // constructor
    // getters and setters
}
```

Now you may want to create another class which is a list of Account. This class will handle getting accounts from the list as an object. For example you may have method called `getNextAccount` which will walk through the list and grab strings and create an account object.

For example:

```
Account getNextAccount() {
    // seek to the starting position of this account
    String name = acc.goToNext();
    String username = acc.goToNext();
    ....
    return new Account(name, username, ...);
}
```

Your code:

```
LinkedList<Account> account = new LinkedList<Account>();
```

isn't correct. Based on the linked list you have, it appears that 9 nodes of the list will create an account object which suggest that this list should be String list not account list. so your linked list should be:

```
LinkedList<String> accountsList = new LinkedList<String>();
```

Now turning to your logic, I believe that you want to create some kind of matching percentage based on different criteria. If the first if condition is true then the match percent is 90%. But here's the problem, suppose that the first if condition is true so the matching percentage should be 90% but the problem is that the second if condition will be true too no matter what is the state value because you are using `if` not `if else` statement. This will be confusing for the user, imagine that your program displays this:

```
User: <user_name> is a 90% match!
User: <user_name> is a 70% match!
```

This is confusing, so you want to use `if else` statements.

Also you may want to create a method that handles printing in the text area. So change your design, try to follow OOP principles, Java is an OOP language and fix your logic and you'll have your date matching program running.